User-Agent in request header not available
I'm capturing the User-Agent property of Request Headers for a website and observed that for around 20% of the requests, the property itself is unavailable.
NameValueCollection nvcReqHeaders = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;
foreach (string key in nvcReqHeaders.AllKeys)
{
   Log.AppendLine(key + " : " + nvcReqHeaders[key]);
}

I would like to understand, what could be the reasons for this. Does it happen when the page requests are not from browsers? Could this be from bots?
